# How to active side menu in react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to active side menu in react application. I am using ListItem for display side menu in my application. But in side menu when I click on ListItem then it will redirect to new page. So How can I selected or active side menu. I tried to active using state but page is redirect to another page. So state will not work.

```
//import React from "react";
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Drawer from "@material-ui/core/Drawer";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Divider from "@material-ui/core/Divider";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";

import { Link } from "./Router";
import TimerIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Timer";
import AssignmentIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Assignment";
import ReportIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Report";
import TimelineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Timeline";
import TodoIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PlayCircleFilledWhite";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    })
  },
  appBarShift: {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 36
  },
  hide: {
    display: "none"
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
  },
  drawerOpen: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen
    })
  },
  drawerClose: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
    }),
    overflowX: "hidden",
    width: theme.spacing.unit * 7 + 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: theme.spacing.unit * 9 + 1
    }
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    padding: "0 8px",
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3
  }
});

class MiniDrawer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    selectedIndex: 0
  };

  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleDrawerClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
          position="fixed"
          className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
            [classes.appBarShift]: this.state.open
          })}
        >
          <Toolbar disableGutters={!this.state.open}>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="Open drawer"
              onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
              className={classNames(classes.menuButton, {
                [classes.hide]: this.state.open
              })}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
              Initio Technologies
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
          variant="permanent"
          className={classNames(classes.drawer, {
            [classes.drawerOpen]: this.state.open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !this.state.open
          })}
          classes={{
            paper: classNames({
              [classes.drawerOpen]: this.state.open,
              [classes.drawerClose]: !this.state.open
            })
          }}
          open={this.state.open}
        >
          <div className={classes.toolbar}>
            <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
              {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
                <ChevronRightIcon />
              ) : (
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              )}
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            <ListItem
              button
              key="Time Tracker"
              component={Link}
              to="/timetracker"
            >
              <ListItemIcon>
                <TimerIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Time Tracker" />
            </ListItem>

            <ListItem
              button
              key="Project"
              component={Link}
              to="/project"
            >
              <ListItemIcon>
                <AssignmentIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Project" />
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem button key="Kanban" component={Link} to="/kanban">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <TimelineIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Kanban" />
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem
              button
              key="Todo"
              component={Link}
              to="/todo"
            >
              <ListItemIcon>
                <TodoIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Todo" />
            </ListItem>

            <ListItem button key="Reports" component={Link} to="/reports">
              <ListItemIcon>
                <ReportIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Reports" />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
          <Divider />
        </Drawer>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

MiniDrawer.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(MiniDrawer);
```

Anyone please suggest me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: how about based on router link address?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to what I can think:

1. Have a Wrapper Component something like this:

```
const Wrapper = () => (
   <React.Fragment>
      <Sidebar />
      <Content />
   </React.Fragment>
)
```

In `Content` you can use route based rendering to switch the content. And thus manage `state` in sidebar.

2. Get the location of where your app is and setting the active item using this key.

You can use `react-router` to handle routing.

Hope this helps!